# How to call a function within getStaticProps on user interaction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to call a function to fetch data from an API whenever a user clicks a button.

Currently, the user clicks a button to toggle a value in DynamoDB. Dynamo updates in the value, but the data that was initially pulled from the database on page load is not updated to showcase the new data.

How can I all this function on every user interaction's with the button:

```js
const {data} = await SSR.API.graphql({
    query: listSites,
    variables: {
      id: params.parkCode,
      filter: {name: {eq: params.parkCode}},
    },
  })
```

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Parallax} from 'react-parallax'
import {AiFillCaretDown} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid'

import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import {MdBookmark, MdBookmarkBorder} from 'react-icons/md'
import {BsCheckLg} from 'react-icons/bs'

import checkUser from '../../hooks/checkUser'

// GraphQL
import {API, Auth, withSSRContext} from 'aws-amplify'
import {createSite, updateSite} from '../../src/graphql/mutations'
import {listSites} from '../../src/graphql/queries'

export default function Park({park, allSites}) {
  const user = checkUser()
  const router = useRouter()
  // console.log(allSites)

  const [toggleDropdown, setToggleDropdown] = useState(false)
  const [selectedCollection, setCollection] = useState(null)

  const {name, description, parkCode, designation, images} = park
  const {url, altText, caption, credit} = images[0]

  // Filter parks that match parkpage to the logged-in user
  const filteredSite = allSites.owner == user?.username ? allSites : null

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMembers()
  }, [])

  const fetchMembers = async (index) => {
    const SSR = withSSRContext()
    let data = await SSR.API.graphql({
      query: listSites,
      variables: {
        id: parkCode,
        filter: {name: {eq: parkCode}},
      },
    })

    let siteData = data.data.listSites.items
    console.log(siteData)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (filteredSite?.bookmarked) {
      setCollection('BOOKMARKED')
    } else if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == false) {
      setCollection('UNBOOKMARKED')
    } else if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == null) setCollection(null)
  }, [allSites, selectedCollection])

  const openDropdown = () => {
    if (!user) alert('Please sign in or create an account')

    if (user) {
      if (toggleDropdown) {
        setToggleDropdown(false)
      } else {
        setToggleDropdown(true)
      }
    }
  }
  const handleDBQuery = async () => {
    if (filteredSite?.bookmarked) {
      setCollection('BOOKMARKED')
    } else if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == false) {
      setCollection('UNBOOKMARKED')
    } else if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == null) setCollection(null)

    try {
      user
        ? setCollection('BOOKMARK')
        : alert('Please sign in or create an account')

      const siteInfo = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        name: parkCode,
        bookmarked: true,
        owner: user?.username,
      }
      // A site does not exist, create a new entry
      if (filteredSite == null) {
        await API.graphql({
          query: createSite,
          variables: {input: siteInfo},
          authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
        })
        console.log(`${name} added`)
      }
      // A site exists, update it
      else {
        console.log(filteredSite?.bookmarked)
        if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == false) {
          await API.graphql({
            query: updateSite,
            variables: {
              input: {
                id: filteredSite.id,
                bookmarked: true,
                owner: user?.username,
              },
            },
            authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
          })
          setCollection('BOOKMARK')
          console.log(`${name} Bookmarked`)
        } else if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == true) {
          await API.graphql({
            query: updateSite,
            variables: {
              input: {
                id: filteredSite?.id,
                bookmarked: false,
              },
            },
            authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
          })
          setCollection(null)
          console.log(`${name} Unbookmarked`)
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }

  // Close dropdown when user interacts with it
  useEffect(() => setToggleDropdown(false), [selectedCollection])

  return (
    <Layout>
      <button
        onClick={() => router.back()}
        className="text-sm text-gray-600-700">
        ↞Back to Results
      </button>

      {/* Title */}
      <span className="block mb-2 text-center">{designation}</span>
      <h1 className="mb-5 font-bold text-center text-green-800 text-7xl">
        {name}
      </h1>

      <code>{selectedCollection}</code>

      {/* Image */}
      <figure>
        <Parallax
          bgImage={url}
          bgImageAlt={altText}
          strength={100}
          style={{borderRadius: '12px'}}>
          <div className="h-[450px]" />
        </Parallax>
        <figcaption className="mt-3 text-sm italic text-center">
          <span>{caption}</span>
          <span className="italic"> {credit}</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>

      <hr className="my-12 border-gray-400" />

      {/* Collection */}
      <div className="relative my-8 w-max">
        {/* Button */}
        <div className="flex">
          {(!filteredSite?.bookmarked ||
            filteredSite?.owner != user?.username) && (
            <button
              onClick={handleDBQuery}
              className="relative flex items-center gap-3 text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-700 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-offset-4 focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-blue-500 focus:transition-none">
              <span className="flex items-center gap-3 px-4">
                <MdBookmarkBorder />
                <span>Want to Visit</span>
              </span>
            </button>
          )}

          {filteredSite?.bookmarked && filteredSite?.owner == user?.username && (
            <button
              onClick={handleDBQuery}
              className="relative flex items-center gap-3 text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-700 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-offset-4 focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-blue-500 focus:transition-none">
              <span className="flex items-center gap-3 px-4">
                <MdBookmark />
                <span>Bookmarked</span>
              </span>
            </button>
          )}

          {selectedCollection == 'VISITED' && (
            <button
              onClick={() => setCollection(null)}
              className="flex items-center gap-3 px-4 py-2 pr-6 text-white bg-green-600 rounded-md hover:bg-green-700 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-offset-4 focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-blue-500 focus:transition-none">
              <BsCheckLg />
              <span>Visited</span>
            </button>
          )}

          {/* Arrow */}
          {selectedCollection != 'VISITED' && (
            <button
              onClick={openDropdown}
              className={`px-4 py-3 pl-4 text-white rounded-r-md focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-offset-4 focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-blue-500 focus:transition-none ${
                selectedCollection == 'VISITED'
                  ? 'bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700'
                  : 'bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700'
              }`}>
              <AiFillCaretDown />
            </button>
          )}
        </div>

        {/* Dropdown */}
        {(selectedCollection == null || selectedCollection == 'BOOKMARK') && (
          <button
            onClick={() => setCollection('VISITED')}
            className={`shadow-lg absolute items-center w-full gap-3 mt-2 text-black bg-blue-300 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-400 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-offset-4 focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-blue-500 focus:transition-none`}>
            <span
              className={`flex items-center gap-3 px-4 ${
                toggleDropdown ? 'flex' : 'hidden'
              }`}>
              <BsCheckLg />
              <span className="py-2">Visited</span>
            </span>
          </button>
        )}
      </div>

      {/* Description */}
      <h3 className="mb-3 text-3xl font-bold text-green-800">Overview</h3>
      <p className="mt-4">{description}</p>

      {/* Images */}
      <h3 className="mt-24 text-3xl font-bold text-green-800 mb-7">
        More Images
      </h3>
      <section className="gap-10 columns-1 sm:columns-2 md:columns-3">
        {images.map((img, index) => {
          return (
            <figure
              key={index}
              className="mb-10 text-center break-inside-avoid-column">
              <img className="rounded-xl" src={img.url} alt={img.altText} />
              <figcaption className="mt-4 text-sm italic text-gray-600 ">
                {img.altText}
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          )
        })}
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const URL = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/'

  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch(
    `${URL}parks?limit=465&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': '*',
      },
    }
  )

  const parks = await res.json()

  const paths = parks.data.map((park) => {
    return {
      params: {
        parkCode: `${park.parkCode}`,
      },
    }
  })

  return {paths, fallback: false}
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const URL = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/'
  const {params} = context

  // Call API Data
  const res = await fetch(
    `${URL}parks?parkCode=${params.parkCode}&limit=465&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': '*',
      },
    }
  )

  const parkData = await res.json()

  // Call User Data
  const SSR = withSSRContext()
  const {data} = await SSR.API.graphql({
    query: listSites,
    variables: {
      id: params.parkCode,
      filter: {name: {eq: params.parkCode}},
    },
  })

  console.log('**********************')
  console.log('**********************')
  // console.log(data.listSites.items[0])

  return {
    props: {
      park: parkData.data[0],
      allSites: data.listSites.items[0],
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: As you pointed out, `getStaticProps` fetches your data at build time. You'll have to use an alternative like [fetching on the client side](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side) or refactoring to `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I am also use getStaticPaths on this dynamic page (`[park].js`) and I can't use both functions

Comment: @BrendanBond, I've refactored my code and moved the API request within the page component in an useEffect hook. This still does not load the data when a user changes it in the database. Please check the updated code

Comment: 1. Does this code run? E.g. where does `setSiteData` come from? Are you using amplify and/or withSSRContext correctly? A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or even just posting all of your component, would go a long way here, it's hard to tell what's going on. 2. For client side fetching, you don't use `withSSRContext`, you can just use amplify's [normal client-side fetch API](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/js/). On the client side, you want to be fetching data just like a normal React app.

Comment: If what you want is the statically generated page to update you should look into [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration). Or, as mentioned before, go full SSR and use `getServerSideProps` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves I think that is what I am looking for. The page should update when a user clicks on a button to update the database, not only after 60 seconds.

Comment: On-demand regeneration is not supported yet.